# Google Cloud / Firebase Functions: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I've created this function:

```
async function getRoomTempFromRoomId(roomId) {
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("sensors").where("room", "==", roomId).where("type", "==", "temperature").limit(1).get();
    var values = []
    values = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { return doc.data().value });
    return values[0];
}
```

Now when I call this function using `console.log(await getRoomTempFromRoomId("1234"))`, I receive the following error:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

The same code works on other Firebase projects

Comment: Firebase Functions works on node v8 by default, what version is running your cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing it in your question, but the function that contains the call to `await getRoomTempFromRoomId` is itself not marked `async`.  You can only use `await` if the function that immediately encloses it is an `async` function.  Not that await will still not work if it's inside an anonymous function that's inside an async function, because the callback function itself is not async.